# How to select an element in protractor having multiple classes?

Tags: angularjs, testing, jasmine, protractor, end-to-end

I have a div like this:

```
<div class="class1 class2 class3" ng-click="displayItems(category.categoryId, category.categoryDescription, category.associatedToElements, 'isItemChecked')"> </div>
```

When I am trying to get the element in Protractor by css:

```
var elementList =  element.all(by.css('class2'));
```

I am getting undefined.

When I am trying the same with ng-click:

```
var elementList = element.all(by.css('[ng-click="displayItems(category.categoryId, category.categoryDescription, category.associatedToElements, "isItemChecked")"]'))
```

still I am unable to track any element.

Suggestions are most welcome.

This is my code:

```
var categoryList, firstCategory;
beforeEach(function(){
    categoryList = element.all(by.css('.class2'));
    firstCategory = categoryList.last();
});

it('Should display values correctly', function(){
    firstCategory.click();
});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try replace `class2` to `.class2`.

Comment: On giving a dot I am getting element not visible error.

Comment: so element is found then?:) Are you sure it is visible during the test?

Comment: No the test is failing. It is unable to find the elements.

Comment: @JyotirmoyPan the answer is correct. You have a different problem - element is found but not visible.

Answer (score 34):

If you are learning how to use protractor I would suggest you to try [elementor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/elementor). It will suggest selectors based on the currently selected item.

You can do this:

```
$('.class1.class2.class3')
```

It is the same as:

```
element(by.css('.class1.class2.class3'))
```